# How to Cut a String After a Certain Number of Characters

Tags: php, string, separator

http://kavtelishvili.com/imedi/script_v_1/ Here's my website where i have a text field named quote. limit on this text field is 160 characters, after 160 characters user can't type any more, i want to keep typing but on another page, is it possible to give a page separator after  every 160 characters and count pages? (160 character is a one page).

Comment: to detect the user input (before submiting it) you need JS or Jquery can you use them ?

Comment: just so I understand this correctly, you only want to get 160 characters at a time, even though it means you have to get the data through multiple requests?

Comment: @Jhecht on each page i can have 160 characters, but maybe text is bigger then 160 characters, so i need to separate after 160 characters to know i have a second or maybe third page. for example: i have a text and it includes 350 characters after i paste this text in my quote field and want it to be separated like Page 1 - 160 characters Page 2 - 160 characters and Page 3 - 30 characters. (160+160+30=350)

Comment: Why only 160 characters is my question? Why not just use all of the characters at once so it lessens your calls to the server.

Comment: @Jhecht
when i send this on e mail i want this text to be separated after 160 characters, email reader should know how many page animation he has to do to create animation. this is a kind of brief, sending information to graphic designer to create an animation. so i need this separated pages with 160 characters.

Comment: I can't imagine why your email reader would only want 160 character in an email. That could get really, really annoying. My best solution for you is to remove the character limit from the field and then use php's `strlen()` and `str_split()`. Please give both of those functions a google and update your question as needed.

Comment: @Jhecht
http://youtu.be/b_VMSUrpRhU here's animation link on youtube.

i want to remove character limit and have string after 160 characters in text (something like this "-----" after 160 characters)